# Erro de compilação com arquivo de cabeçalho

Tags: c++, compilação

Não consigo criar classes com arquivo de cabeçalho. Quando crio o arquivo .h e crio a implementação das funções membro no arquivo .cpp dá error ao compilar. Pensei que fosse eu, então fui no site [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/cpp/header-files-cpp?view=vs-2019) um exemplo que eles deram. Deu erro no meu compilador, mas em um compilador online funcionou.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
// my_program.cpp
#include "my_class.h"

using namespace N;

int main()
{
    my_class mc;
    mc.do_something();
    return 0;
}

// my_class.cpp
#include "my_class.h" // header in local directory
#include <iostream> // header in standard library

using namespace N;
using namespace std;

void my_class::do_something()
{
    cout << "Doing something!" << endl;
}

// my_class.h
namespace N
{
    class my_class
    {
    public:
        void do_something();
    };

}
```

Comment: Parece erro de link. Coloque toda a mensagem de erro. O ideal seria exibir a chamada do compilador, que parâmetros está sendo passado para ele.

Comment: Em meu computador rodou sem problemas em Windows no Visual Studio 2019 com CL19.27. O código está exatamente assim?

Comment: Sim. Este exemplo eu copiei diretamente do site da Microsoft. Pensei que estivesse fazendo algo errado, mas é o meu próprio computador. Peço perdão pela demora em responder.